# It is possible to create flat array from query results in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

Query

```
select *
from (
    select [1] a
    union all
    select [1,2] a
    union all
    select [2] a
) q;
```

Result (3 rows)

```
[1]
[1,2]
[2]
```

Expected result (1 row)

```
[1,1,2,2]
```

It is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure. You just need a couple of array functions.

```
select arrayFlatten(groupArray(*))
from (
    select [1] a
    union all
    select [1,2] a
    union all
    select [2] a
) q;
```

`groupyArray` gives you `[[1],[1,2],[2]]`, essentially grouping all the results in one array.
`arrayFlatten` flattens the above array, resulting in `[1,1,2,2]`.

Answer (score 5):

Alternate way using [Array](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/combinators/#agg-functions-combinator-array)-combinator:

```sql
SELECT groupArrayArray(*)
FROM 
(
    SELECT [1] AS a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [1, 2] AS a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [2] AS a
) AS q
/* result
┌─groupArrayArray(a)─┐
│ [1,1,2,2]          │
└────────────────────┘
*/
```

Comment: Interesting. Are you aware whether this yields better performance compared to my approach?

Comment: @MatthewFormosa not sure, to know it needs to make tests on a big amount of data or look at source code.

Comment: I've just tested it, with big (about 35M arrays) dataset, groupArrayArray is 30% faster